# Vpnbook doesn't work after upgrade to Ubunntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: networking, upgrade, 22.04, vpn, openvpn

After updating Ubuntu to 22.04. LTS I can not use Vpnbook any more.

When I try to launch OpenVpn client with any of the profiles, it ends with error message"

2022-08-28 02:20:08 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
2022-08-28 02:20:08 NOTE: --fast-io is disabled since we are not using UDP
2022-08-28 02:20:08 OpenSSL: error:0A00018E:SSL routines::ca md too weak
2022-08-28 02:20:08 Cannot load inline certificate file
2022-08-28 02:20:08 Exiting due to fatal error

How to solve this problem?

With Best Regards,
Dragan